# Why are strings favored over defined symbols (constants)?

Tags: python

I notice that Python frequently uses strings where you could use some kind of defined symbol, like a constant. For example, to paraphrase a sample of code from `argparse`:

```python
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')
```

Rather than requiring the use of the string `'store_const'`, why didn't the developers define a constant-like symbol, e.g. `ArgumentParser.STORE_CONST`?

I'd prefer the constant because code editors can easily see them in the module and use them as suggestions for code completions. Also, a typo in a string may not cause an error, but a typo in a defined symbol probably would. I've seen several examples in Python of strings used this way, but it's not as common in other languages, like Java or PHP.

Comment: You would probably need to ask the developers or Guido himself. Outside of that you are just going to get opinions.

Comment: While an `enum`-like construct will give a compilation error on a language like Java or C++ if you spell some constant name wrong, even providing ready-made constants in Python will provide an error only at runtime, only when you execute exactly that code path. IOW: given that we are comparing runtime-checked strings with runtime-lookup of runtime-defined symbols, there's not such a big difference.

Comment: (also, notice that this seems mostly a matter of preference even in the Python standard library - if you look up the `re` module all the regexp flags are top-level constants in the `re` module)

Comment: See e.g. http://mauveweb.co.uk/posts/2014/12/dont-name-strings.html for some other arguments

Answer (score 1):

many libraries do use "constants" ...  including argparse

you could just as easily pass in `argparse._StoreConstAction`

it also provides the following named constants

```
SUPPRESS = '==SUPPRESS=='

OPTIONAL = '?'
ZERO_OR_MORE = '*'
ONE_OR_MORE = '+'
PARSER = 'A...'
REMAINDER = '...'
_UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR = '_unrecognized_args'
```

another option would be to write your own constants class that encompasses all of the magic numbers and or strings that bother you

Comment: Indeed various `Action` subclasses are listed: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/argparse.py#l1233. Note that they're explicitly excluded from the public interface, though.

Comment: so you cannot do `from argparse import _StoreConstAction` ... but it still gives him the autocomplete with `import argparse;argparse._St...`